# Querying a json column and export data inside a XML

Tags: json, xml, postgresql

Currently working on a report to export some values that are sent to an API. The DB is Postgresql and there's a column that stores this data.

This is an example:

```
{
  "url": "https://www.z.com/psd/pmzservice.asmx",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/xml"
  },
  "body": "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.a.org/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:pvs=\"http://www.z.com/WebServices/PMZService/\">\r\n <soap:Header/>\r\n <soap:Body>\r\n <pvs:ValidateTinName>\r\n <pvs:TinName>\r\n <pvs:TIIN>83163943234</pvs:TIIN>\r\n <pvs:LName></pvs:LName>\r\n <pvs:FName>Dedetizadora Johnsnville Ltda</pvs:FName>\r\n <pvs:Encryption></pvs:Encryption>\r\n <pvs:Giin></pvs:Giin>\r\n </pvs:TinName>\r\n <pvs:CurUser>\r\n <pvs:UserID></pvs:UserID>",
  "method": "POST",
  "field_id": 10896231321,
  "timeout": 65
}
```

This is my first time dealing with XML and based on what I've been searching. I made this query using the XPath function to get the value inside **FName**

```
select  xpath(
            '/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/pvs:ValidateTiinName/pvs:TinName/pvs:FName/text()',
            (a.json_column::json->>'body')::xml,
            ARRAY[
              ('soap', 'http://www.a.org/05/soap-envelope')::xml,
              ('pvs', 'http://www.z.com/WebServices/PMZService')::xml
            ]::xml[]
          )::text AS fname_value
from table a
```

But when I run it I'm facing the following issue: **ERROR: cannot cast type record to xml**

Can you please help me to understand how to export the data stored in **FName** and **TIIN**?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the column data type for the source? and the XML content inside the JSON body has several XML errors (it's "badly formed!") Is that XML something you can fix? The <pvs:CurUser> opening tag does not have a corresponding closing tag.
The XML content ends prematurely. The closing tags for <pvs:ValidateTinName>, <soap:Body>, and <soap:Envelope> are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems you are experiencing include the problem that the embedded XML isn't well formed, so while you can usejson finctions to get the body element, any xml function on that will fail. The pvs:CurUser opening tag does not have a corresponding closing tag. The XML content ends prematurely. The closing tags for pvs:ValidateTinName, soap:Body, and soap:Envelope are missing.

The following tries to identify what the issue are, note that the second insert contains fixes to the body xml portion. Then, in the final query, you can get the TIIN and FName once the xml is well formed:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  json_value jsonb
);
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
INSERT INTO mytable (json_value)
VALUES
  ('{
    "url": "https://www.z.com/psd/pmzservice.asmx",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/xml"
    },
    "body": "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.a.org/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:pvs=\"http://www.z.com/WebServices/PMZService/\">\r\n <soap:Header/>\r\n <soap:Body>\r\n <pvs:ValidateTinName>\r\n <pvs:TinName>\r\n <pvs:TIIN>83163943234</pvs:TIIN>\r\n <pvs:LName></pvs:LName>\r\n <pvs:FName>Dedetizadora Johnsnville Ltda</pvs:FName>\r\n <pvs:Encryption></pvs:Encryption>\r\n <pvs:Giin></pvs:Giin>\r\n </pvs:TinName>\r\n <pvs:CurUser>\r\n <pvs:UserID></pvs:UserID>",
    "method": "POST",
    "field_id": 10896231321,
    "timeout": 65
  }');
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 1
> ```

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  (json_value ->> 'body') body
FROM 
  mytable;
```

| id | body |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.a.org/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:pvs="http://www.z.com/WebServices/PMZService/"> <soap:Header/> <soap:Body> <pvs:ValidateTinName> <pvs:TinName> <pvs:TIIN>83163943234</pvs:TIIN> <pvs:LName></pvs:LName> <pvs:FName>Dedetizadora Johnsnville Ltda</pvs:FName> <pvs:Encryption></pvs:Encryption> <pvs:Giin></pvs:Giin> </pvs:TinName> <pvs:CurUser> <pvs:UserID></pvs:UserID> |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

```
SELECT 
  (xpath('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/pvs:ValidateTinName/pvs:TinName/pvs:FName/text()', XMLPARSE(CONTENT json_value ->> 'body'), ARRAY[ARRAY['soap', 'http://www.a.org/05/soap-envelope'], ARRAY['pvs', 'http://www.z.com/WebServices/PMZService/']]::TEXT[]))[1]::TEXT AS fname,
  (xpath('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/pvs:ValidateTinName/pvs:TinName/pvs:TIIN/text()', XMLPARSE(CONTENT json_value ->> 'body'), ARRAY[ARRAY['soap', 'http://www.a.org/05/soap-envelope'], ARRAY['pvs', 'http://www.z.com/WebServices/PMZService/']]::TEXT[]))[1]::TEXT AS tiin
FROM 
  mytable;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid XML content
> DETAIL:  line 13: Premature end of data in tag CurUser line 12
>  <pvs:UserID></pvs:UserID>
>                           ^
> line 13: chunk is not well balanced
>  <pvs:UserID></pvs:UserID>
>                           ^
> ```

```
INSERT INTO mytable (json_value)
VALUES
 ('{
    "url": "https://www.z.com/psd/pmzservice.asmx",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/xml"
    },
    "body": "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.a.org/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:pvs=\"http://www.z.com/WebServices/PMZService/\">\n<soap:Header/>\n<soap:Body>\n<pvs:ValidateTinName>\n<pvs:TinName>\n<pvs:TIIN>83163943234</pvs:TIIN>\n<pvs:LName></pvs:LName>\n<pvs:FName>Dedetizadora Johnsnville Ltda</pvs:FName>\n<pvs:Encryption></pvs:Encryption>\n<pvs:Giin></pvs:Giin>\n</pvs:TinName>\n<pvs:CurUser>\n<pvs:UserID></pvs:UserID></pvs:CurUser>\n</pvs:ValidateTinName>\n</soap:Body>\n</soap:Envelope>\n",
    "method": "POST",
    "field_id": 10896231321,
    "timeout": 65
  }');
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 1
> ```

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  (json_value ->> 'body') body
FROM 
  mytable;
```

| id | body |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.a.org/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:pvs="http://www.z.com/WebServices/PMZService/"> <soap:Header/> <soap:Body> <pvs:ValidateTinName> <pvs:TinName> <pvs:TIIN>83163943234</pvs:TIIN> <pvs:LName></pvs:LName> <pvs:FName>Dedetizadora Johnsnville Ltda</pvs:FName> <pvs:Encryption></pvs:Encryption> <pvs:Giin></pvs:Giin> </pvs:TinName> <pvs:CurUser> <pvs:UserID></pvs:UserID> |
| 2 | <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.a.org/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:pvs="http://www.z.com/WebServices/PMZService/"> <soap:Header/> <soap:Body> <pvs:ValidateTinName> <pvs:TinName> <pvs:TIIN>83163943234</pvs:TIIN> <pvs:LName></pvs:LName> <pvs:FName>Dedetizadora Johnsnville Ltda</pvs:FName> <pvs:Encryption></pvs:Encryption> <pvs:Giin></pvs:Giin> </pvs:TinName> <pvs:CurUser> <pvs:UserID></pvs:UserID></pvs:CurUser> </pvs:ValidateTinName> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope> |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

```
SELECT 
  id,
  (xpath('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/pvs:ValidateTinName/pvs:TinName/pvs:FName/text()', XMLPARSE(CONTENT json_value ->> 'body'), ARRAY[ARRAY['soap', 'http://www.a.org/05/soap-envelope'], ARRAY['pvs', 'http://www.z.com/WebServices/PMZService/']]::TEXT[]))[1]::TEXT AS fname,
  (xpath('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/pvs:ValidateTinName/pvs:TinName/pvs:TIIN/text()', XMLPARSE(CONTENT json_value ->> 'body'), ARRAY[ARRAY['soap', 'http://www.a.org/05/soap-envelope'], ARRAY['pvs', 'http://www.z.com/WebServices/PMZService/']]::TEXT[]))[1]::TEXT AS tiin
FROM 
  mytable
where id = 2
```

| id | fname | tiin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Dedetizadora Johnsnville Ltda | 83163943234 |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IM9UnvPB)